# WebAPI and OData Functions

Tags: asp.net-web-api, odata

I am using a webapi to get data. The API limits results to 100. In this case there are 2481, but because of this limitation I cannot get all of the records needed without using OData functions. I have been told to use the skip function, but the documentation on this isn't very helpful for someone who hasn't used it before.

My call is as follows:

```
    https://accounting.sageone.co.za/api/2.0.0/TaxInvoice/get?apikey={xxxxxxxxxx}&companyid=12345&includeDetail=true&$orderby=Created%20desc
```

Below is a snipet of the first result returned:

```
> {
>     "TotalResults": 2481,
>     "ReturnedResults": 100,
>     "Results": [
>         {
>             "DueDate": "2018-10-31T00:00:00Z",
>             "FromDocument": "",
>             "AllowOnlinePayment": true,
>             "Paid": false,
>             "Status": "Unpaid",
>             "Locked": false,
>             "CustomerId": 3148838,
>             "CustomerName": "Cell C Limited",
>             "SalesRepresentativeId": 37307,
>             "SalesRepresentative": {
>                 "ID": 37307,
>                 "FirstName": "David",
>                 "LastName": "Markman",
>                 "Name": "David Markman",
>                 "Active": true,
>                 "Email": "davidm@infoslipsconnect.com",
>                 "Mobile": "",
>                 "Telephone": "",
>                 "Created": "2018-10-18T12:42:31.233",
>                 "Modified": "2018-10-18T12:46:49.01"
>             },
>             "Modified": "2018-10-18T12:46:49.01",
>             "Created": "2018-10-18T12:42:31.233",
>             "ID": 483959431,
>             "Date": "2018-10-18T00:00:00Z",
>             "Inclusive": false,
>             "DiscountPercentage": 0,
>             "TaxReference": "4870194356",
>             "DocumentNumber": "INV03357",
>             "Reference": "14480 - October Print & Post",
>             "Message": "",
>             "Discount": 0,
>             "Exclusive": 98243.04,
>             "Tax": 14736.46,
>             "Rounding": 0,
>             "Total": 112979.5,
>             "AmountDue": 112979.5,
>             "PostalAddress01": "Cell C ",
>             "PostalAddress02": "Waterfall Campus",
>             "PostalAddress03": "C/O Maxwell Drive and Pretoria Road",
>             "PostalAddress04": "Buccleuch",
>             "PostalAddress05": "",
>             "DeliveryAddress01": "September 2018 Print & Post Distribution",
>             "DeliveryAddress02": "",
>             "DeliveryAddress03": "",
>             "DeliveryAddress04": "",
>             "DeliveryAddress05": "PO: TBC",
>             "Printed": true,
>             "Editable": true,
>             "HasAttachments": false,
>             "HasNotes": false,
>             "HasAnticipatedDate": false,
>             "Lines": [
>                 {
>                     "SelectionId": 4804411,
>                     "TaxTypeId": 2691481,
>                     "ID": 328907379,
>                     "Description": "CELL C PRINT & POST ",
>                     "LineType": 0,
>                     "Quantity": 1,
>                     "UnitPriceExclusive": 0,
>                     "Unit": "",
>                     "UnitPriceInclusive": 0,
>                     "TaxPercentage": 0.15,
>                     "DiscountPercentage": 0,
>                     "Exclusive": 0,
>                     "Discount": 0,
>                     "Tax": 0,
>                     "Total": 0,
>                     "Comments": "",
>                     "AnalysisCategoryId1": 16041,
>                     "UnitCost": 0
>                 },
>                 {
>                     "SelectionId": 12926677,
>                     "TaxTypeId": 2691481,
>                     "ID": 328907380,
>                     "Description": "CellC: PDF Compiled",
>                     "LineType": 0,
>                     "Quantity": 52926,
>                     "UnitPriceExclusive": 0.34,
>                     "Unit": "",
>                     "UnitPriceInclusive": 0.39,
>                     "TaxPercentage": 0.15,
>                     "DiscountPercentage": 0,
>                     "Exclusive": 17994.84,
>                     "Discount": 0,
>                     "Tax": 2699.23,
>                     "Total": 20694.07,
>                     "Comments": "",
>                     "AnalysisCategoryId1": 16041,
>                     "UnitCost": 0
>                 },
>                 {
>                     "SelectionId": 12926854,
>                     "TaxTypeId": 2691481,
>                     "ID": 328907382,
>                     "Description": "CellC: Rounding Difference",
>                     "LineType": 0,
>                     "Quantity": 1,
>                     "UnitPriceExclusive": -238.16,
>                     "Unit": "",
>                     "UnitPriceInclusive": -273.88,
>                     "TaxPercentage": 0.15,
>                     "DiscountPercentage": 0,
>                     "Exclusive": -238.16,
>                     "Discount": 0,
>                     "Tax": -35.72,
>                     "Total": -273.88,
>                     "Comments": "",
>                     "AnalysisCategoryId1": 16041,
>                     "UnitCost": 0
>                 },
>                 {
>                     "SelectionId": 12926687,
>                     "TaxTypeId": 2691481,
>                     "ID": 328907383,
>                     "Description": "CellC: PDF Print",
>                     "LineType": 0,
>                     "Quantity": 109782.5,
>                     "UnitPriceExclusive": 0.73,
>                     "Unit": "",
>                     "UnitPriceInclusive": 0.83,
>                     "TaxPercentage": 0.15,
>                     "DiscountPercentage": 0,
>                     "Exclusive": 80141.23,
>                     "Discount": 0,
>                     "Tax": 12021.18,
>                     "Total": 92162.41,
>                     "Comments": "",
>                     "AnalysisCategoryId1": 16041,
>                     "UnitCost": 0
>                 },
>                 {
>                     "SelectionId": 12926854,
>                     "TaxTypeId": 2691481,
>                     "ID": 328907384,
>                     "Description": "CellC: Rounding Difference",
>                     "LineType": 0,
>                     "Quantity": 1,
>                     "UnitPriceExclusive": -87.82,
>                     "Unit": "",
>                     "UnitPriceInclusive": -100.99,
>                     "TaxPercentage": 0.15,
>                     "DiscountPercentage": 0,
>                     "Exclusive": -87.82,
>                     "Discount": 0,
>                     "Tax": -13.17,
>                     "Total": -100.99,
>                     "Comments": "",
>                     "AnalysisCategoryId1": 16041,
>                     "UnitCost": 0
>                 },
>                 {
>                     "SelectionId": 12926687,
>                     "TaxTypeId": 2691481,
>                     "ID": 328907385,
>                     "Description": "CellC: Hand Delivery",
>                     "LineType": 0,
>                     "Quantity": 2,
>                     "UnitPriceExclusive": 0.34,
>                     "Unit": "",
>                     "UnitPriceInclusive": 0.39,
>                     "TaxPercentage": 0.15,
>                     "DiscountPercentage": 0,
>                     "Exclusive": 0.68,
>                     "Discount": 0,
>                     "Tax": 0.1,
>                     "Total": 0.78,
>                     "Comments": "",
>                     "AnalysisCategoryId1": 16041,
>                     "UnitCost": 0
>                 },
>                 {
>                     "SelectionId": 12926854,
>                     "TaxTypeId": 2691481,
>                     "ID": 328907386,
>                     "Description": "CellC: Rounding Difference",
>                     "LineType": 0,
>                     "Quantity": 1,
>                     "UnitPriceExclusive": -0.01,
>                     "Unit": "",
>                     "UnitPriceInclusive": -0.01,
>                     "TaxPercentage": 0.15,
>                     "DiscountPercentage": 0,
>                     "Exclusive": -0.01,
>                     "Discount": 0,
>                     "Tax": 0,
>                     "Total": -0.01,
>                     "Comments": "",
>                     "AnalysisCategoryId1": 16041,
>                     "UnitCost": 0
>                 },
>                 {
>                     "SelectionId": 12926761,
>                     "TaxTypeId": 2691481,
>                     "ID": 328907387,
>                     "Description": "CellC: Nixie",
>                     "LineType": 0,
>                     "Quantity": 1,
>                     "UnitPriceExclusive": 432.28,
>                     "Unit": "",
>                     "UnitPriceInclusive": 497.12,
>                     "TaxPercentage": 0.15,
>                     "DiscountPercentage": 0,
>            "Exclusive": 432.28,
>             "Discount": 0,
>              "Tax": 64.84,
>               "Total": 497.12,
>                "Comments": "",
>                 "AnalysisCategoryId1": 16041,
>                  "UnitCost": 0
>               }
>            ]
>         },
```

I need to do the following: Return all records where a specific field ("Created") contains the current year, even if there are more than 100 results. I assume that the $search and skip functions would need to be used, but I am not sure of the syntax.

Thanks,
Steven

Comment: If this is not your api then skip and take will not help unless a similar mechanism is exposed.

Comment: The developer of the API advised that skip should be used so I presume that it will work if the syntax is correct.

Comment: @StevenNel all OData clients expose operators like Skip. In C#, you'd write a LINQ query with a `Skip(100)`. What language and client are you using? Why create a raw URL? In any case you use a *client* and inspect the URL it generates

Comment: I'm connecting to the API using Excel. At the moment just using the external data source function, but I could use VBA.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to documentation [here](https://www.odata.org/documentation/odata-version-2-0/uri-conventions/), you should concantenate skip argument into URL.

Something like:

```
https://accounting.sageone.co.za/api/2.0.0/TaxInvoice/get?apikey={xxxxxxxxxx}&companyid=12345&includeDetail=true&$skip=100&$orderby=Created%20desc
```

The example provided was:

```
https://services.odata.org/OData/OData.svc/Products?$skip=2&$top=2&$orderby=Rating
```

You may need to fiddle a little but that appears to be the method.

Answer (score 0):

To return all records where a specific field ("Created") contains the current year, you need to append the below filter criteria to the url. You can see other OData Date function supported [here](https://www.odata.org/documentation/odata-version-2-0/uri-conventions/).

```
&$filter=year(Created) eq 2018
```

OData handles the pagination for the services which might return huge data. As the API limit is 100 which indicates the page size of data, so you will get maximum 100 records per service call. To get records from 101 to 200, you need to skip first 100 by appending `$skip=100` to the url. Also if you need to fetch records from 201 to 300 then append $skip=200 to the url and so on until you get 2481 records. That means you need to call the service 25 times by increasing the `$skip` value.

So with additional filter and skip query, you need to append below query string to existing url

```
 &$filter=year(Created) eq 2018&$skip=100
```

Also, if you want to fetch records less than 100 per service call then you need use `$top` query. Let's say if you have page size of 50 in your application, then append `$top=50` to the query string.